# Duplicate entry X for key 'PRIMARY', but no duplicates found

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I run this code:

```
INSERT INTO x.contacts (`id`, `name`, `address`) SELECT `id`, `name`, `address` FROM y.contacts;
```

And it gives me the following error:

> **Error:** Duplicate entry '6323' for key 'PRIMARY'

When I search for the ID 6323 in the table of `y.contacts`, it only appears once.

So why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please show us the _full_ `INSERT` statement you are using, not a paraphrased version.

Comment: INSERT INTO x.contacts (
 `id`,
 `name`,
 `address`
)

SELECT 
 `id`,
 `name`,
 `address`
FROM y.`contacts`;

Comment: Any good suggestions on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a record with ID 0 in the auto increment column that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your table `.contacts`, it looks like the table already has a value 6323 in it.

If you check in your table `.contacts` you will find that the row with id 6323 is already present and hence the error.

Comment: (Sorry, the tables is called x.contacts).
The table is empty, i truncate it before I run the code

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you try duplicating an existing row. The ID already exists once, and when executing your command, you duplicate it.

Comment: (Sorry, the tables is called x.contacts).
The table is empty, i truncate it before I run the code

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue getting the error but there's no record with the ID. In my case `REPAIR TABLE tablename` fixed the issue.

```
mysql> repair table items ;
+------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                   |
+------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| mydb.items       | repair | warning  | Number of rows changed from 56263 to 56264 |
| mydb.items       | repair | status   | OK                                         |
+------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.40 sec)
```

MySQL version:

```
% mysql --version                                                                                               /www/stackful.com
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.47, for redhat-linux-gnu (i386) using readline 5.1
```